# Vue JS access data from parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, bulma

I am using the vue cli webpack and have an array of 'links' in my App.vue file. I want to figure out how I can use items from 'links' in my navbar.vue file. I have tried using props, the inherit property and passing it with :links="links" but nothing seems to work. Just to specify I am also using bulma the css library in case thats important.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <navbar links="links"></navbar>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import navbar from './components/navbar'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        navbar
    },
    data () {
        return {
            links: [
                {name: 'Link 1', url: '#'},
                {name: 'Link 2', url: '#'}
            ]
        }
    }
   }
</script>
```

navbar.vue:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar has-shadow">
        <div class="navbar-menu">
            <a class="navbar-item">
                {{brand}}
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item" v-for='link in links'>
                {{link.name}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    import app from '../App'

    export default {
        name: 'navbar',
        inherit: true,
        data () {
            return {
                brand: 'Vue Website',
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

I am pretty certain I have checked all methods I could find online but none of them worked or I could work out how to use them, if anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: Have you tried reading [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `links` as a prop in `navbar.vue`, otherwise Vue will ignore it:

```
export default {
    name: 'navbar',
    props: ['links'], // declare links as a prop
    data () {
        return {
            brand: 'Vue Website',
        }
    },
}
```

Then in the parent you can use it:

```
<navbar :links="links"></navbar>
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to "bind" your property "links".

Instead of

```
<navbar links="links"></navbar> 
// This will give you a string "links"
```

Use:

```
<navbar :links="links"></navbar>
```

More information:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props